# What are the reasons for developing the wrinkles in the eyes? Is sun exposure an important cause?

Tags: wrinkles

Some people develop these before compared to their counterparts. Does the geography has an important effect, because of a sun exposure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skin wrinkles are generally caused by [a breakdown of the collagen framework within the skin](http://www.webmd.com/beauty/cosmetic-procedures-collagen#1).

> Collagen is a key part of your skin's structure. It forms a network of fibers within your skin that acts like a framework.
>
> In young skin, the collagen framework is intact and the skin remains moisturized and elastic. Over time, the support structure weakens and the skin loses its elasticity. The skin begins to lose its tone as the collagen support wears down.

Wrinkles and other signs of skin ageing [can be influenced by habits and behaviours during a person's life](http://www.webmd.boots.com/healthy-skin/guide/ageing-skin-do-you-look-older-than-you-should). Avoiding some risk factors for premature skin ageing can help keep skin looking younger for longer.

As well as smoking causing premature skin aging,

> Wrinkles at the corners of the eyes (crow's feet) or between the eyebrows (frown lines) are thought to be caused by small muscle contractions. Over a lifetime, habitual facial expressions like frowning, smiling or squinting leave their mark on our skin.

The first link states that

> Using your facial muscles -- smiling, frowning, or squinting, for instance -- is part of expressing yourself. That's normal, but it does stress the collagen in your skin. Over time, that stress adds up and contributes to facial lines and wrinkles.